# Error in OpenMP, trying to vectorize a Matrix Multiplication for loop

Tags: c, openmp, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to vectorize an old matrix multiplication program I made, specifically this function using a parallel for call in openmp. I keep getting this error:

```
matrix_multiply.c(26): error: invalid entity for this variable list in omp clause
    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static) default(shared) private(i,j,k,sum)
```

Any help would be much appreciated as I've tried looking up the error and can't find any documentation that was helpful. I'm compiling using ICC if that makes a difference.

```
void matrix_mult(int * matrix_A, int * matrix_B, int n)
{
    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static) default(shared) private(i,j,k,sum)
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k<n; k++)
            {
                int index_a = i * n +k;
                int index_b = j + k * n;
                sum += matrix_A[index_a] * matrix_A[index_b];

            }
            matrix_B[i * n + j] = sum;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using threads (OpenMP) is not a good way to get additional speed on matrix multiplication. Rather, think deeply about your cache utilization, memory layout, and loop blocking. ([Details](https://github.com/flame/how-to-optimize-gemm/wiki)).

Comment: @Richard is right, doing matrix multiplication optimally is hard. So it's much simpler  to use an optimised matrix multiply that someone else has spent time on, such as the ones in Intel MKL (https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl ) which is gratis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're two things worth mentioning here:

1. What you're actually doing here isn't vectorizing (although your compiler might be doing it for you), it is parallelizing. Here, you're creating threads to split the work among. Each thread may or may not use the CPU's vector units to spreed the computations up even more, but it has nothing to do with the parallelization directives you've put.
2. The error the compiler reports only says that it doesn't known the variables you've listed in your `private` directive. Indeed, if you look closer, neither of `i`, `j`, `k`, and `sum` have been declared before the directive line. So for the compiler, they don't exist (yet). As a matter of fact, since you only declare them when you need them (which is very good), which is inside the `parallel` region, you don't have to declare them `private`anyway since they already are private to the the thread where they are created. So just removing the `private` clause should fix your issue.

Finally, if performance matters to you, rather than trying to parallelize or vectorize this code, just consider replacing it by an effective library call that will do it for you. Unfortunately, since you're dealing with integers, BLAS won't do. But I'm sure there are good options out there for that.